# Add new value and key in existing NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have the following array, however, is there a way to add a new `key` and `value` ( such as age) for each dictionary item in the `NSMutableArray` after the following initialization.

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Joe",@"firstname",
                   @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Simon",@"firstname",
                   @"Templar",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                   @"Pond",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can do this using dip linking .**

Here is Sample Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary mutableCopy = (NSMutableDictionary )CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)originalDictionary, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1429997-cfpropertylistcreatedeepcopy?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

If you can define your array of dictionaries as mutable dictionaries, then you can do what you want like this:

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Joe",@"firstname",
                          @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Simon",@"firstname",
                          @"Templar",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                          @"Pond",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         nil];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in names) {
    dic[@"age"] = @21;
}
```

Notice that each of the elements in the initial array are now `NSMutableDictionary` intsances instead of `NSDictioanry`. If for some reason you cannot do that, then you would need to get each dictionary from the array, convert it to a mutable instance and then replace the relevant array element with the new dictionary instance.

If you can't create `NSMutableDictionary` instances for the array, then the code you need would look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Joe",@"firstname",
                          @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Simon",@"firstname",
                          @"Templar",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                          @"Pond",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         nil];
[names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dic, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dic2 = [dic mutableCopy];
    dic2[@"age"] = @21;
    names[idx] = dic2;
}];
```

Comment: you bring a new variable `dic` into the picture, but I do not see how do you change `names` object. By the way, AFnetworking convert the json object into `NSDictionary`

Comment: See the `for` loop to see how `dic` came into being. The code is simply iterating through each element in the array. Since you presented the code with the array being created via code, the above solution would work. But if you get the array via an API call, then that won't work. You'd need to convert the dictionary to a mutable dictionary as I mentioned, first.

Answer (score 1):

If Want to add key and value in Dictionary then take NSMutableDictionary And add key and value in dictionary.

Below is Code for That:

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Joe",@"firstname",
                              @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                              nil],
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Simon",@"firstname",
                              @"Templar",@"surname",
                              nil],
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                              @"Pond",@"surname",
                              nil],
                             nil];
    for (int i=0; i<names.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *name = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:names[i]];
        NSDictionary *test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Test" forKey:@"Demo"];
        [name addEntriesFromDictionary:test];
        names[i] = name;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",names);
```